# Type declaration file and call signature error

Tags: typescript

Due to the lack of official d.ts file for a slug module, I get all kinds of error trying it to work.

First, here is the file where I import the module.

```
import * as slug from "slug" // Had to create a custom d.ts empty file to avoid compile error as no official definition file existed

let slugify = function (data: string): string {
    let slugified: string = slug('ééé aaa ooo') // error here

    return slugified

}

export default slugify
```

And here is the empty d.ts file i had to create to prevent import error message from the compiler:

```
declare module "slug" {

}
```

new problem is on slug('ééé aaa ooo') :

```
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
```

How can I resolve this ? Should I add "fake" content in the d.ts file ?

Comment: Instead of the import try `declare var slug`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler needs to know how slug works and you can let it know by exporting a declaration of that function—something that represents how slug looks in JavaScript—from the module in the definition file.

Here's one way of doing it:

```
declare module "slug" {
    interface SlugOptions {
        lower?: boolean;
        // ...add the other options here...
    }

    function slug(val: string, optionsOrReplacement?: SlugOptions | string): string;

    export = slug;
}
```

I believe the only way to import this library is to use `require` since it [doesn't use](https://github.com/dodo/node-slug/blob/0f28b4d0b3ece403dbd630d81ee49375e3af5953/slug.js) a named/default export in the js code:

```
import slug = require("slug");
```

Comment: thanks, this is an elaborated solution that does the job. However, I went with the easy route, and used a simple require import instead.